# How to verify if ng-form is touched

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, typescript

I have created a 'wrapper' directive, which functions as a form-element wrapper. One or more inputs can be wrapped inside of this directive.

The directive itself contains the `ng-form` directive, so I can check for each instance if there are errors and if the (ng-model)inputs are invalid.

In my wrapper template I want to add an 'error' class when:

- One or more inputs are $invalid
- AND:

  - The form is submitted
  - OR
  - One or more inputs are $touched

This is my current (stripped) wrapper directive:

```
export class FormElementWrapper {
    public transclude = true;

    public template = `
        <div ng-form="formElementWrapper"
             ng-class="{'has-error': showError }" ng-transclude>
        </div>
    `;

    public link = (scope, element, attrs) => {
        // custom keep track of touched
        var touched = false;

        var isSubmitted = function(): boolean {
            var form: any = scope.formElementWrapper;
            return form.$$parentForm.$submitted;
        };

        scope.$watch(() => {
            // show error when:
            // - one ore more inputs are invalid
            // - AND
            // -- form is touched
            // -- OR
            // -- parent form is submitted
            var submitted = isSubmitted();
            return scope.formElementWrapper.$invalid && (touched || submitted);
        }, (val) => {
            scope.showError = val;
        });

        // override $setPristine to reset the custom touched property
        var origPristine = scope.formElementWrapper.$setPristine;
        scope.formElementWrapper.$setPristine = () => {
            touched = false;
            origPristine();
        }

        // bind to blur events of all inputs
        element.on("blur", ":input", () => {
            touched = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Question: How can I know if one or more elements are $touched? The ngFormController doesn't have that property. Currently I am binding to the `blur` event of inputs, but I can imagine that other directives that use `ng-model` don't have to be inputs per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically use a negation of the oposite of untouched which is `$pristine`. Therefore you can check it by using `if(!form.$pristine)` then means that form is touched.

According to [form.FormController docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController), `$pristine` is `True` if user has not interacted with the form yet.

However, if you like to extend the `NgModelController.$touched` to your FormController, you can simply add a `$touched = true` to your form, when any element gets blured. It can be done by using a directive concurrent with `ngModel` and change its `FormController.$touched` value when the element gets triggered by a `blur` event.

The following example implements this solution.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('ngModel', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: ['^?form'],
      priority: 1000,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrls) {
        var ngFormCtrl = ctrls[0];

        if (ngFormCtrl) {
          elem.on('blur', function onBlurEvent() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              ngFormCtrl.$touched = true;
              elem.off('blur', onBlurEvent);
            });
          });
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('myController', function($rootScope) {

    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.model = {
      name: 'lenny',
      age: 23
    };
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController as $ctrl">
  <form name="$ctrl.myForm" novalidate>
    <label>Name :
      <input name="test1" ng-model="$ctrl.model.name">
    </label>
    <label>age :
      <input name="test2" ng-model="$ctrl.model.age">
    </label>

    <label>{{ $ctrl.myForm.$touched ? 'Touched' : 'Untouched'}}</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this because it was documented as 'interacted with the form', but it seems to work as the opposite of the `$dirty` flag, not `$touched`

Comment: Yes, it means that the form object (model) is intouched not the DOM input element.

Comment: @devqon Actually, touched as the ngModelController touched isn't built in on ngFormController, if you want it, it must be implemented (it's not difficult by the way).

Comment: This looks nice! One question: Why do you unbind the blur afterwards?

Comment: @devqon Because once it has been touched, you don't need that listenner anymore. But it doesn't make much difference at all, just one listener less. Also I had done that in a deprecated way, I've updated my answer to use `off()` instead.

Comment: One more question; What if `ng-model` is used on a custom directive? Without inputs/ blur events? Then this won't work right?

Comment: Yes, it won't work that way, you would have to use a different way to catch the touched state rather than on blur

Comment: Thank you, you answer got my on my right thinking track :)